# Running a script to automate inputs in GDB

Tags: python, powershell, gdb

I have a project that I am working on for class. The idea is there are 7 phases, each filled with assembly instructions. For each phase, it's looking for a particular input that passes the "tests" and unlocks the next phase. My job is to investigate and reverse engineer the assembly instructions to figure out what it wants. I am stuck on phase 6, which asks for 6 numbers, each between 1 and 6. For example, it wants an input like 5 4 5 3 1 6. Instead of investigating the code, I figured it'd be fun to try and write a python script to input every permutation of the above requirements.

I have a txt file filled with every permutation. Ideally the script would follow the workflow mentioned later, and then enter two inputs each try. It will enter a file with the previous answers, so running the command r answers.txt. Then the next input takes a string, which is what I enter as the answer. I either pass the phase or fail and try again. So the script has to enter the r previousanswers.txt, then a line from the permutations until it runs out or hits the answer.

I've tried using subprocesses and such, but I am way in over my head because there are a few issues I cannot get past:

1. I need to enter a couple commands before I even get to the part where I can enter my answer.

   - The workflow looks like this: wsl > cd ~/lab > gdb phases > r previousanswers.txt > (my-
     answer).
   - If the answer is wrong, it resets back to the gdb part. So I need to re-enter all previous
     answers so that I can skip to the phase I can currently on.
2. Every time I get a script that works in the output of VScode, I cannot get it to work in a command line. For example, the first line in my .py file is "import subprocess." It's trying to enter that as a line in the answer.
3. Currently with the code I have, it freezes after the wsl command.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['wsl'], shell=True)
subprocess.run(['cd', '~/lab'], shell=True)
subprocess.run(['gdb', 'phases'], shell=True)
with open('output.txt') as f: #output.txt is the file with all permutations
    for line in f:
        subprocess.run(['r', 'previousanswers.txt'], shell=True)
        subprocess.run([line], shell=True)
```

I've tried os.system, subprocess, etc. I cannot find anything online either and I am stuck. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advanced.

Comment: The [docu for subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) says `Wait for command to complete, then return`, so it's not surprising that this freezes. And each call of `subprocess.run` creates a new process.